# Сохранение темы в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-themes

Немного не понимаю как сохранить тему в SharedPreferences, для того, что бы тема сохранялась после перезапуска приложения.
Фрагмент кода:

```
void initThemeListener() {

lightThemeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "light", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
});

darkThemeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

    }
});

}
```

Comment: android-studio метка никак не связана с вашим вопросом

Comment: если не учитывать что он написан под ним то вероятнее всего да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас будет только два варианта темная и светлая то можно записывать в память bool значение, например что `light == true`. Для этого объявляем в классе где вы это делаете (активность или фрагмент) переменную:

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
```

в методе `onCreate()` если это активность присваиваем ей значение:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   sPref = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
   ...
}
```

дальше при установке светлой темы пишем в память:

```
sPref.edit().putBoolean("theme", true).commit();
```

после записи считываем где вам нужно:

```
sPref.getBoolean("theme", false);
```

и дальше через условие устанавливаем тему:

```
if (sPref.getBoolean("theme", false)){
// light == true
}else{
// light == false
}
```

если же у вас будет больше чем 2 темы то нужно добавлять какие-то идентификаторы и писать уже например int. Вот [доки](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) по этой теме и [пример](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: Благодарю вас Andrew!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.